# Select distinct rows by to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following table

```
VacancyID  VacancyName  HourRate  MarketID
------------------------------------------
1          manager      15        NULL
2          manager      17        1
3          sales        9         NULL
           assistant
4          store keeper 12        NULL
5          store keeper 13        1
6          customer     10        NULL
           consultant
```

**VacancyID** - unique identifier of vacancy

**VacancyName** - name of vacancy

**HourRate** - hour rate

**MarketID** - unique identifier of market where vacancy is open. There are separate Markets table, but it doesn't matter for this question.

I need to select all distinct vacancies (by VacancyName) from above table for MarketID == 1. But if some vacancy is not opened in market 1, it should be taken from row with MarketID == NULL

So for MarketID == 1 result should look like

```
VacancyID  VacancyName  HourRate  MarketID
------------------------------------------
2          manager      17        1
3          sales        9         NULL
           assistant
5          store keeper 13        1
6          customer     10        NULL
           consultant
```

Sales assistant and Customer consultant vacancies are not exist for MarketID == 1, so they are taken from MarketID == NULL. (vacancies from rows with MarketID == NULL should be taken when there is no such vacancy for specific market)

What SQL command should be used to achieve such a result?

Note: The database is on SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subquery to filter on `MarketID` that are either `null` or `1`, and then use `row_number()` to assign a rank to each record within groups of record having the same `VacancyName`, while giving a lower priority to the `null` values. Then, the outer query just filters on the top record per group.

```
select VacancyID, VacancyName, HourRate, MarketID 
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by VacancyName 
            order by coalesce(MarketID, 0) desc
        ) rn
    from mytable t
    where coalesce(MarketID, 1) = 1
) x
where rn = 1
order by VacancyID
```

To query on a different MarketID, you just need to change the `where` clause, the query will work the same way (assuming that `n > 0`):

```
where coalesce(MarketID, <n>) = <n>
```

[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=df46f32930edbb4ea74cdbb394d0966f):

```
VacancyID | VacancyName         | HourRate | MarketID
--------: | :------------------ | -------: | -------:
        2 | manager             |       17 |        1
        3 | sales assistant     |        9 |     null 
        5 | store keeper        |       13 |        1 
        6 | customer consultant |       10 |     null
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT T.* 
FROM Your_Table T INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(VacancyID) AS VacancyID, VacancyName 
    FROM Your_Table
    WHERE MarketID = 1
    GROUP BY VacancyName 
) X
ON T.VacancyID = X.VacancyID

UNION

SELECT T.* 
FROM Your_Table T 
WHERE VacancyName  NOT IN 
                        (
                            SELECT VacancyName 
                            FROM Your_Table
                            WHERE MarketID = 1
                        )  

AND MarketID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

An `or` and `not exists` seems to do what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where marketID = 1 or
      (marketID is null and
       not exists (select 1
                   from t t2
                   where t2.VacancyName = t.VacancyName and 
                         t2.marketId = 1
                  )
       );
```

With an index on `(VacancyName, MarketId)`, I would expect this to have the very good performance on large data sets